# Solve $\frac{dA}{dt}=-10A$, $A(0)=5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $\frac{dA}{dt}=-10A$, $A(0)=5$

So I figured this came from the exponential growth equation where:

$A(t)=Ce^{kt}$ and $\frac{dA}{dt}=Cke^{kt}$

But I'm confused by what "solve" means?  Am I just trying to find a function that represents this equation?

So I think

$5=A(0)=Ce^{-10(0)}=C$

Which I think means:

$-10(5)e^{-10t}$ or $-50e^{-10t}$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: It means use $A(0)$ to find $C$ and plug that into your differential equation.

Comment: We "solve" a differential equation by finding a function that meets the initial conditions and also satisfies the DE.

Comment: It wants you to find a function $A(t)$ which is satisfied by the ODE and initial condition that you have there.

Comment: @LanierFreeman so did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that if we set $-10 = \alpha(t)$ and set
$\gamma(t) = \int -10 dt = -10t,$ Note that
$$\frac{d}{dt} (e^{10t}A) = e^{10t}\frac{dA}{dt} + 10e^{10t}A
= e^{10t}(\frac{dA}{dt} + 10A) = e^{10t}0 = 0$$
$$\implies \int \frac{d}{dt} (e^{10t}A) dt = e^{10t} A
= \int 0 dt = C$$
for some constant $C$
$$\implies A(t) = Ce^{-10t}.$$
Since $A(0) = 5,$
$$A(0) = 5 = Ce^0 = C \implies C = 5$$
$$\implies A(t) = 5e^{-10t}.$$